# Android Emulator virtual scene option is gone

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am trying to create a new emulator with the back camera set to virtual scene, however, it is not in the options. What should I do to get that option? Or what are the packages I need to install to get it? Thanks

[image: No virtual scene option for back camera when creating emulator]

[image: Packages]

[image: Packages]

Comment: Which version of android studio are you running?  Versions older than 3.1 won't show this option in the AVD wizard.

Comment: it is the latest 3.1

Comment: I think this problem has been solved after installing Android Studio 3.2. You can just give it a try!

Comment: @thousight did you resolve this? If so, can you please post the correct answer.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately...